# how to jump to specific line number of a PS dataset in mainframes

Tags: mainframe, file-management, ispf

My PS file has 5millionreccords.
I want to goto 2.5 millionth record.
can I go directly there without pressing mF8 too many times

Answer (score 2):

I got it now. You have to give L 500000  or what ever line number you want to go. Hit enter. you will reach. Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: L is the LOCATE command. Pressing PF1 takes you into a world of interesting stuff. Consume bit by bite. Practice where necessary. It'll improve your experience with ISPF no end. There are also manuals, but it is a 200m walk with a lot of teasing to get hold of one. Oh, forgetting. They're available online these days.